# Output semantic code blocks with Prism

Tags: javascript, bash, haskell, pandoc, prismjs

I'm inputting markdown data and outputting HTML files with Pandoc. Using the `--no-highlight` flag, I can get the syntax to output without the built-in basic syntax highlighting, and use Prism.js to highlight the code instead, which is much more robust.

However, Prism requires that the `code` or `pre` have `language-*` in the class name. Using php as an example, Pandoc outputs `<pre class="php">`. I've managed to hack it to work by using:

````
```language-php
````

As the start of each code block. However, when I want to export the same code as an EPUB, it won't recognize the language to be able to use the built in syntax highlighting.

Here are the commands I use for EPUB and HTML output:

```
# epub output
pandoc assets/metadata.yaml chapters/*.md -o build/book.epub

# html output
pandoc assets/metadata.yaml chapters/*.md -s --toc --no-highlight  --css ../assets/style.css -A assets/template/footer.html -o build/book.html
```

My issue:

I want to be able to write

````
```php
````

As the start of my code blocks, instead of

````
```language-php
````

So both Prism.js and the built-in syntax highlighter will work, with my EPUB and HTML generation.

If I could get Pandoc to interpret "```php" as `class="language-php"`, this would solve the issue.

[Here is a link](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/3858) on the Pandoc GitHub for someone else with the same issue I'm trying to solve.

Comment: Can't you just `sed '/s/class="php"/class="language-php"/'` ?

Comment: using a [pandoc filter](https://pandoc.org/filters.html) would be much more robust than `sed`...

Comment: That will be very useful, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm for using sed as well, but as a pre-processor. You could write a script like the one below, and name it `pre-process`:

````
#!/bin/bash -e

derived_dir=derived
rm -fr ${derived_dir} && mkdir -p ${derived_dir}
for file in $*
do
    cat ${file} | sed 's/```php/```language-php/g' > ${derived_dir}/$(basename ${file})
done
echo "${derived_dir}/*"
````

Then you could use ```` ```php ```` in your source, and produce html via:

`pandoc assets/metadata.yaml $(pre-process chapters/*.md) -s --toc --no-highlight  --css ../assets/style.css -A assets/template/footer.html -o build/book.html`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Absolutely amazing! Thank you so much, this works perfectly!